# How to get substring from beginning to one character after certain character?

Tags: c#, string, substring

I would like to get a substring from the beginning of a String until (and including) one character AFTER a period.

Example:

```
convertedTempLabel.Text = TemperatureConversion(decimal.Parse(tempTextBox.Text),
            fromTemperature,
            toTemperature).ToString();
```

This is returning a String value of a temperature. The problem is that it's return many decimal values after the period. I only want the first character after the period. So if it returns 67.8933333, I want to get the substring 67.8

I can add `.substring(0,4)` but if the value returns three digits before the period it won't include the digit after the period. I basically want to get a substring based on the array spot AND a character value.

Thanks.

Comment: What is TemperatureConversion?

Comment: TemperatureConversion returns a decimal value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `TemperatureConversion` method returns decimal, then you should just provide numeric format string with desired number of decimal places you want to get:

```
 .ToString("0.0")
```

Or

```
 .ToString("N1")
```

Further reading [Custom Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a string formatter for number:

```
var dec = new decimal(123.123456);
dec.ToString("0.#"); // will output 123.1 or 123 if there is no decimal value
dec.ToString("0.0"); // will output 123.1 or 123.0 if there is no decimal value
```

Comment: I like the "0.#" addition to the answer above, it makes it look neater. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a new string and iterate the old string till you find the period , you will append it and the number after it only and break from the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you want your output with one decimal place without rounding it:

```
string.Format("{0:0.0}", Math.Truncate(yourdoublevalue * 10) / 10);
```